# Android: Reading from a file and increasing the readed lines not working

Tags: android, for-loop, readline

I have a file with different questions and I need to read them one after another when the user clicks the "Next Button". However, I can only read the first line and the following one and after that one the layout remains the same and doesn't work. I will appreciate some help in order to read total questions. Here is part of my code:

```
public class Questions {
int i = 0;
int questionCount = 0;
int category;
String question;
int questionNumber=1;

void currentQuestion(Context context, int cat) {
    category = cat;



    String questionFile = "";



        questionFile = "VerbalSup1.txt";
        questionCount = 25;





    Log.i("Question", questionFile + ": " + questionCount);
    try {
        InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(questionFile);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        // Skips lines
        for (i = 0; i< questionNumber; i++) {
            reader.readLine();

        }
        question = reader.readLine();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
void Next(){
    questionNumber=questionNumber + 1;
}
```

Here is the next button:

```
bNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    questions.Next();
                     questions = new Questions();
                     questions.Next();
                     currentQuestion();


            }


        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are resetting the `questions` object so it will get only the first line..
Here:

```
questions.Next();
questions = new Questions(); // this is wrong as the counts will be reset to defaults
questions.Next();
currentQuestion();
```

You should have:

```
questions.Next();       
currentQuestion();
currentQuestion();
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Your welcome, I'm glad it helped! Also you can vote this as an answer if helped..